# Rest Assured base URI configuration

Tags: rest, rest-assured

How rest assured is identifying base URI defined in another class while making http calls? E.g. I have set baseURI in class A and I am making http call from Class B but still while completing http call Rest Assured is able to take into account base URI defined in class B so how this is happening?

Comment: Please provide sample code for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [RestAssured.baseURI](https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/1.2.3/com/jayway/restassured/RestAssured.html#baseURI) in your class `A`, which sets the base URI statically and so is used for all future REST calls. When tests in your class `B` run after that line executes then, the base URI you defined is used.